# How do you place Banner Ads or Interstitial Ads in Windows Forms

Tags: c#

I wish to place test Banner Ads or Interstitial Ads in Windows Forms.  I am using Windows 8.1 Pro, VS Community 2015 and have downloaded 
[Microsoft Store Advertising SDK for Windows and Windows Phone 8.x][1]

Test Banner Ads work OK in UWP Windows 8.1; but,

there is no AdControl or AdMediatorControl in the Toolbox when using Windows Forms Application 8.1.

I have added a PictureBox; but, can’t add a Reference Extension [as per attached 2 screen dumps].
In UWP Windows I am able to add Ad.Mediator SDK for Windows 8.1 XAML. This is not available when I use a Win Form.
Thanks for your prompt response.

[WinForm Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaIhw.png)
[UWP Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R02O.png)

Comment: The banner is picture... Why don't you use PictureBox?

Comment: try including the libraries you used in your UWP which include the AdControl. Then you can use it in your WinForms.

Comment: I have added a PictureBox; but, can’t add a Reference Extension [as per attached 2 screen dumps].
In UWP Windows I am able to add Ad.Mediator SDK for Windows 8.1 XAML. This is not available when I use a Win Form.

Answer (score 0):

Could not find Banner Ads using WinForms. Seems odd, anyway Banner Ads work ok in UWP Windows 8.1 with VS2015.
Just drag an “AdControl” from the Toolbox to your project in MainPage.xaml.
You will have to change the ApplicationId, AdUnitId, Width and Height as follows

```
enter code here 
 <UI:AdControl ApplicationId="3f83fe91-d6be-434d-a0ae-7351c5a997f1" 
                  AdUnitId="10865270" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                  Margin="486,515,0,0" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Width="728"
                  Height="90"/>
```

Using Width X Height of 300x250, 728x90, 160x600 or 300x600 for Win 8.1.

Hope this helps.